# Появление элемента после длительного нажатия на блок

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Здравствуйте! Имеется список приложений, на мобильных устройствах предусмотрено появление кнопки при длительном нажатии любого из пунктов списка. До этого с версткой подобных элементов не сталкивался, прошу подсказать как такие вещи реализуются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите ваш `layout` для одного элемента. (ваш код) так легче будет вам это объяснить.

Comment: У вас точно Android? А то ответы на JavaScript'ах пошли. Что за технологию используете? Phonegap?

Comment: Saidolim, речь идет о мобильной версии сайта, тег android поставил так как, мне кажется, он делает описание проблемы более точной)

Comment: @Игорь мобильная версия сайта может быть разной - через `webView`(простой браузер с подгрузкой всего хтмл и жс кода) или нативным, обращаясь напрямую к бд.

Comment: @Asgard, вариант первый)

Comment: @Игорь вам помог один из ответов?

Comment: @Asgard, да, благодарю за проявленный интерес.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var shows = 0;
  $('#longClick').mousedown(function(){
    shows = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#shower').show();
    }, 2000);
});
  
  $('#longClick').mouseup(function(){ 
     clearTimeout(shows);
   });
   $('*').not($('#shower')).mousedown(function(){
         $('#shower').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='longClick'>Click me 2 second</div>
<ul id='shower' style='display:none'>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
<div class='other'>Click for close</div>
<div class='other'>Click for close</div>
```

Comment: Mojito, благодарю за ответ. Если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста, дополните скрипт - нужно чтобы при нажатии на сторонние области это окошко исчезало..

Comment: попробуйте так...

Answer (score 2):

Для этого в `item_layout` который есть дизайн одной строки, поставте дизайт внутри `RelativeLayout` и потом кнопку и прозрачным фоном поставте поверх всех других элементов. и установите

```
visibility="GONE"
```

а при нажатии поменяйте его на `VISIBLE`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final int IDM_OPEN = 101; 
public static final int IDM_SAVE = 102; 

final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
registerForContextMenu(textview); 

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_OPEN, Menu.NONE, "Открыть");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_SAVE, Menu.NONE, "Сохранить");
}
```

[Источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/contextmenu.php)

Такую кнопку можно вызвать еще и так. Это называется контекстное меню.